# Android EditText Keyboard making Fragment disappear

Tags: android

In one of the fragments in my app I have an edittext, and whenever I click on it the keyboard comes up and all the content in the fragment just disappears, including the edittext. I can still type on the keyboard, and after I press the back button, everything comes back and whatever I type is showing on the edittext, but how do I stop everything from disappearing?

Below is the code for the fragment and its layout.

Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PaymentsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payments, container, false);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:hint="Enter Something"

    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"

    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Button"

    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText2"

    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference : [Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

> **android:windowSoftInputMode**
>
> The adjustment made to the activity's main window — whether it is
> resized smaller to make room for the soft keyboard or whether its
> contents pan to make the current focus visible when part of the window
> is covered by the soft keyboard.
>
> **adjustResize**
>
> The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard on screen.
>
> **adjustPan**
>
> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft
> keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned
> so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users
> can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable
> than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to
> get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

**Use this way in manifest** :

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> </activity>
```

Comment: activity.window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE) does indeed solve the problem. But this is a HACK. The Fragment does disapear and never reappear once the keyboard is closed

Answer (score 0):

I still reproduce it in the case of a "Multiline EditText in Scrollview in fragment in ConstraintLayout" even on Android 8. Using a SingleLine does not create any issue.

It is happening because the dynamic height of a EditText does not work well in this situation.
This solution was hackish, but it does work like a charm if you can afford to fix the number of lines:

- Create a custom class LabelEditView extending EditText
- Add an attribute

> ```
>   <declare-styleable name="LabelEditView">
>     <attr name="label_edit_line_count" format="integer" />
>   </declare-styleable>
> ```

- In the constructor call:

> ```
> setLineCount(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.LabelEditView_label_edit_line_count,
> ```
>
> 1));

Then, finally, the interesting piece of code:

```
  /**
   * Set the number of visible lines. Does not support to switch between modes or font
   */
  public void setLineCount(int lineCount) {
    if (lineCount <= 1) {
      setSingleLine(true);
    } else {
      setSingleLine(false);
      setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
      setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

      // Fix around EditText in Scrollview in fragment in ConstraintLayout
      Paint.FontMetrics fm = getPaint().getFontMetrics();
      int textHeight = (int) ((fm.bottom - fm.top) * (lineCount + 0.5));
      setMaxHeight(textHeight);
      setHeight(textHeight);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Put in AndroidManifest.xml (in your activity):

```
<activity android:name="(activity name)" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```